# How to add some informative text to loading spinner?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-web-components

I have a loading spinner in my lightning component, but I want to add some text for the user to know for example what they are waiting for while its spinning, or just a simple "This might take some time".

Component:

```
<aura:component implements="force:appHostable" controller="mycontroller" access="global">

    <aura:attribute name="Spinner"  type="boolean"  default="false"/>

    <!--Loading Spinner-->
    <aura:if isTrue="{!v.Spinner}">
        <lightning:spinner alternativeText="Loading" variant="brand" size="large"/>
    </aura:if>
    <!--/Loading Spinner-->

</aura:component>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot get custom message with standard `lightning:spinner`. However, you can use the base classes from [slds spinner](https://lightningdesignsystem.com/components/spinners/)

Below is sample:

```
<aura:attribute name="showSpinner" type="Boolean" default="true" />
<aura:if isTrue="{!v.showSpinner}">
    <div class="demo-only" >
        <div class="slds-spinner_container ">
            <div role="status" class="slds-spinner slds-spinner_medium slds-spinner_brand">
                <span class="slds-assistive-text">Loading</span>
                <div class="slds-spinner__dot-a"></div>
                <div class="slds-spinner__dot-b"></div>
                <div class="custom-loading-text">
                    My Custom Loading Text...
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
</aura:if>
```

STYLE:

```
.THIS .custom-loading-text {
    transform: rotate(-90deg);
    position: absolute;
    top: -1.5rem;
    left: -1rem;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

OUTPUT:

[image]

Comment: Many thanks, it works great!

Comment: If this solved your issue, pls mark the answer solved so that the question closes. Pls check https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, all my attempts to place any lightning component inside the spinner body were unsuccessful. Although according to the [`lightning:spinner`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:spinner/specification) specification:

> Attribute Name - **body**, type - **component[]**, access - **global**.       Inherited from `aura:component` The body of
>   the component. In markup, this is everything in the body of the tag.

You can make your own custom spinner or try some workaround to display text of the value of `alternativeText` attribute:

```
<--! spinnerText.cmp -->
<aura:component description="spinnerText">
    <lightning:spinner class="c-spinner" alternativeText="This might take some time" variant="brand" size="large"/>
<aura:component description="spinnerText">

<--! spinnerText.css -->
.THIS.c-spinner .slds-assistive-text {
    clip: unset !important;
    transform: rotate(270deg);
    height: unset !important;
    width: unset !important;
    font-size: x-large;
}
```

[image]

Comment: It is not really a good practice to show alternative text. It is meant to be shown only when the resource is not available - this is standard behaviour - not meant to be manually overridden

Comment: Yes, it is better to write a custom spinner generally. But `alternativeText` attribute works not as `HTML` `alt` attribute. `<lightning:spinner>` animation is drawn by `::before` and `::after` pseudo-elements thus resource-independently. `<lightning:spinner>` should be updated to enable putting another component into the body. So I think for this moment it is not so bad to consider my workaround solution as possible.